# Can someone please explain this eager loading example?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I'm reading the Microsft tutorial about Asp.Net MVC 5 and EF 6 at this link [text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) .
Now I'm confused with the code below.

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id, int? courseID)
{
    var viewModel = new InstructorIndexData();
    viewModel.Instructors = db.Instructors
        .Include(i => i.OfficeAssignment)
        .Include(i => i.Courses.Select(c => c.Department))   
        .OrderBy(i => i.LastName);

    if (id != null)
    {
        ViewBag.InstructorID = id.Value;
        viewModel.Courses = viewModel.Instructors.Where(
            i => i.ID == id.Value).Single().Courses;
    }

    if (courseID != null)
    {
        ViewBag.CourseID = courseID.Value;
        viewModel.Enrollments = viewModel.Courses.Where(
            x => x.CourseID == courseID).Single().Enrollments;
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}

 public class InstructorIndexData
    {
        public IEnumerable<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
```

I thought that these lines of code would load **all **Instructors and for each one the related OfficeAssignment and **all **instructor's Courses with Department related to each Course.

```
viewModel.Instructors = db.Instructors
        .Include(i => i.OfficeAssignment)
        .Include(i => i.Courses.Select(c => c.Department))   
        .OrderBy(i => i.LastName);
```

If so, why after, if an Instructor is seleted (id!=null), the viewmodel Courses are loaded again?

`viewModel.Courses = viewModel.Instructors.Where(i => i.ID == id.Value).Single().Courses;`

Can someone, please, explain?

Comment: EL-Muradny's answer pretty much sums it up, but it'w worth noting that the calls to populate the viewModel.Courses and viewModel.Enrollments aren't reloading from the database, they are pulling the appropriate set of details from the Instructors that were pre-fetched. There is only one query to the database in their example, though I wouldn't call the design efficient as it would certainly strain resources/performance easily with any non-trivial amount of data, but fine as long as data load remains light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first load is to load all the Instructors and their related OfficeAssigments and Courses from the database into the Instructors property of viewModel, just like your understanding, so this is the eager loading part, where all relevant data is fetched from the database.

The second load is to load all the related Courses to the selected Instructor from the Instructors property of viewModel (which was fetched in part1), to the Courses property of viewModel. So this part is not fetching from the database at all, allowing you to not have to open another connection to the database.

Comment: Thank you very much. Somewhere I read that a .Where always imply a SQL to databse. Maybe I misunderstand that.

Comment: .Where() is simple a LINQ syntax that you can use on any Enumerable. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-8.0)